# glob() not returning files with same creation time php

Tags: php, glob

Currently i am using this code to get file in directory, but it only that files which different create date/time. If the files has same time, then it just shows 1 of them.

```
    <?php 
$perpage = 6;
$page = (int)$_GET['page'];
if(!($page>0)) $page = 1;
$offset = ($page-1)*$perpage;
$parm=$_GET['dir'];
$extensions = array('3gp', 'mp4', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp');
$files = glob('files/'.$parm.'/*'.'{'.implode(',', $extensions).'}', GLOB_BRACE);
$files = array_combine(array_map("filemtime", $files), $files);
krsort($files);
$total_files = sizeof($files);
$total_pages = ceil($total_files/$perpage);
$files = array_slice($files, $offset, $perpage);
?>
```

Now please solve this case

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `glob()` function does return what meets the specified criteria!

But the reason for your problem being is because the `array_combine()` function takes the first argument (the array which holds the file times) as the "keys" of the final output array, and as you know there can't be any key duplicates in an array, only the last file among those having the same file time will be added to the final result array.

---

By knowing that, you may think of an alternative way of what your trying to do (since I don't know what are you trying to do!)